# Calling getData on Firebase DatabaseReference returns the data for the parent reference instead

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

#### The problem

Using the Firebase iOS SDK, I'm trying to get data from a child of a top-level node in the database, but fetching from it gives me the data for the whole top-level node.

I have a top-level node in my database. I'm trying to get data from a direct child of that node. So, when I put a breakpoint on this line:

```swift
databaseRef.getData { error, snapshot in
```

and print out `databaseRef` to the console, it displays the URL for child the. But if I put a breakpoint *inside* that closure, and print out the snapshot to the console, it displays the data for the parent. I have the firebase console up side by side, so I can clearly see it.

#### What I've tried

Before you can ask, no, it's not the callback for a different instance, because I've even tried retaining a reference to `databaseRef` in the closure and printing it out again there. The method looks like this:

```swift
func getOnce() -> Future<T?, ReceiveError> {
    let promise = Promise<T?, ReceiveError>()

    let decoder = decoder
    let ref = databaseRef // databaseRef is a property on this object
    databaseRef.getData { error, snapshot in
        print(ref)
        // => https://[REDACTED]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/invite_codes/jake-email_com for example
        print(snapshot)
        // => The content of https://[REDACTED]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/invite_codes
        let result = result(
            forError: error,
            snapshot: snapshot,
            usingDecoder: decoder
        )
        promise.complete(withResult: result)
    }
        
    return promise.future
}
```

`ref` ends up being as expected: it shows the url for the child, and `snapshot` shows the data for the parent.

#### How I get my database reference

I have an existing database reference for the parent. It behaves exactly as expected, vending the data that matches the underlying URL. Its underlying URL looks like:
`https://[REDACTED]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/invite_codes`

The database reference for the child is created by taking a user's email address and replacing the `@` with a `-` and a the `.` with a `_`. So if I input `jake@some.email` the code calls:

```swift
parentReference.child(encodedEmail)
```

where `encodedEmail` is `"jake-some_email"`.

When that reference is printed to the console, its url is as expected, taking the form:
`https://[REDACTED]-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/invite_codes/jake-some_email`

However, when I call `getData(completion:` on it, I get the data of the parent reference, which *contains* the node that URL would represent, as the snapshot ends up looking like:

```
Snap (jake-some_email) {
    "jake-someemail_com" =     {
        // the data that I want
    };
    "another-email_com" =   {
```

etc, etc, etc.

Notice how the above reference is TO `jake-some_email` but it also CONTAINS `jake-someemail_com`. Looking at the database from the Firebase console shows no structure matching that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'd rather not expose my data / database structure to the entire internet. Why is that needed?  The above is an accurate depiction of the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen If I put a breakpoint on this line of Swift code:
`databaseRef.getData { error, snapshot in`
and print the database reference to the console, it spits out the URL for the child node I'm interested in. But if I put a breakpoint inside that closure, and print out the snapshot, it prints out the data of the parent of the database reference printed out on the previous breakpoint.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've put every last bit of non-sensitive data and code into my question now that I possibly can. Care to take another look?

Comment: Thanks for that.  Hmmm.... it sounds unexpect to get the data of the parent node, but I vaguely recall there was an issue in the SDK a while ago. Can you show the a single code fragment that does: "However, when I call `getData(completion:` on it, I get the data of the parent reference"?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've included a more extended code fragment now. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I don't see what could be going wrong there, as it matches pretty close to many of our unit tests. One of the engineers is trying to reproduce the problem. While they do that, I've cleaned up the outdated comments above, and recommend doing the same for yours.

Answer (score -1):

One of our engineers tried to reproduce the problem, but was unable to get the behavior you seem to be having. Since it is a bit longer than fits in a comment, I am posting it as an answer, although I realize it may not actually answer your question.

The code:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
let data = [ "child" : true, "otherChild": true]
let root = Database.database().reference()
let parentRef = root.child("parent")
let childRef = parentRef.child("child")
parentRef.setValue(data)
childRef.getData { err, snap in
    if err != nil {
        print("Error: \(err!)")
    }
    if (snap != nil && snap!.exists()) {
        print(childRef)
        print(snap!)
    }
}
childRef.observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with: { snap in
    print("Snapshot from once: \(snap)")
})
parentRef.getData { err, snap in
    if err != nil {
        print("Error: \(err!)")
    }
    if (snap != nil && snap!.exists()) {
        print(parentRef)
        print(snap!)
    }
}
```

With this, the data in the database becomes:

[image: tree with a parent node with two child nodes as written by the code above]

The output:

```
https://fir-multi-shards.firebaseio.com/parent/child
Snap (child) 1
Snapshot from once: Snap (child) 1
https://fir-multi-shards.firebaseio.com/parent
Snap (parent) {
    child = 1;
    otherChild = 1;
}
```

As you can see the paths and values written match with the two references we have in the code.